# Trouble running Airflow on reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, airflow

We're running an Ubuntu 15.10 virtual machine. I edited the user crontab to have the following lines:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/airflow schedule -D
@reboot /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver -D
```

In the syslog I get the following lines:

```
Feb 16 10:48:58 SERVERNAME cron[723]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Feb 16 10:48:58 SERVERNAME CRON[748]: (username) CMD (airflow schedule -D)
Feb 16 10:48:58 SERVERNAME CRON[749]: (username) CMD (airflow webserver -D)
```

If I run those lines while logged in they work, but not on restart. I'm not all that skilled at Linux, so I'm assuming there's something easy I'm missing here.

I get this output sent to my "Mail" on restart.

```
X-Original-To: analytics
Delivered-To: analytics@PARKAT1TEST
Received: by PARKAT1TEST (Postfix, from userid 1005)
        id 78011101C51; Thu, 16 Feb 2017 12:15:47 -0600 (CST)
From: root@PARKAT1TEST (Cron Daemon)
To: analytics@PARKAT1TEST
Subject: Cron <analytics@PARKAT1TEST> /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver -D
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/analytics>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=analytics>
Message-Id: <20170216181547.78011101C51@PARKAT1TEST>
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 12:15:47 -0600 (CST)

[2017-02-16 12:15:45,610] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-02-16 12:15:45,879] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2017-02-16 12:15:45,908] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar$
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

[2017-02-16 12:15:47,033] {models.py:154} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/analytics/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn server with 4 syncworkers on host 0.0.0.0 and port 8080 with a timeout of 120...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 15, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 423, in webserver
    'gunicorn', run_args
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 523, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 568, in _execvpe
    raise last_exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 558, in _execvpe
    exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

All the files registered in the error message exist; and it still runs fine when logged in and run manually.

Comment: check `$PATH` environment

Comment: The location of the airflow command, `usr/local/bin` is in the `$PATH `environment

Comment: I've also tried putting in the full path in cron; no results. I can copy paste the command into the command line and it works fine.